# Terraform AWS not able to ping, or ssh just created EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, terraform, ping

I would like to ask for assistance.
I wrote terraform script which is creating 5 EC2 instances but I am not able to ping or SSH them.
Do you see any potential issue with this? I have opened icmp, ssh, not when I checked form other computers/sites I get port is closed.
When I create manually EC2 is working from my computer, I am able to ssh/ping, but not with this terraform script.

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 3.0"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "AKxxxxxxxxxxx"
  secret_key = "2CLBj/s9dC5r52Y"
}

# Create a VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "BrokenByteVPC" {
  cidr_block = "192.168.100.0/28"
  tags = {
    Name = "BrokenByteVPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "BrokenbyteLB-subnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.BrokenByteVPC.id
  cidr_block = "192.168.100.0/28"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  tags = {
    Name = "BrokenbyteLB-subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "BrokenByte-gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.BrokenByteVPC.id

  tags = {
    Name = "BrokenByte-gateway"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "BrokenByte-Route-table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.BrokenByteVPC.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.BrokenByte-gateway.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.BrokenbyteLB-subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.BrokenByte-Route-table.id
}


resource "aws_security_group" "allow_traffic" {
  name        = "allow_Traffic"
  description = "Allow SSH,HTTP and HTTPS  inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.BrokenByteVPC.id


ingress {
    description = "Dozvoli SVEEEEEEEE"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

ingress {
    description = "SSH traffic"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

ingress {
    description = "HTTP traffic"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "HTTPS traffic"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Allow_ssh_http_https"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "NginX-public" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.BrokenbyteLB-subnet.id
  #private_ips     = ["192.168.100.2"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_traffic.id]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "NginX-LB" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.BrokenbyteLB-subnet.id
  private_ips     = ["192.168.100.10"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_traffic.id]
}
resource "aws_network_interface" "www1" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.BrokenbyteLB-subnet.id
  private_ips     = ["192.168.100.11"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_traffic.id]
}
resource "aws_network_interface" "www2" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.BrokenbyteLB-subnet.id
  private_ips     = ["192.168.100.12"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_traffic.id]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "www3" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.BrokenbyteLB-subnet.id
  private_ips     = ["192.168.100.13"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_traffic.id]
}

resource "aws_eip" "BrokenByte-PublicIP" {
  vpc                       = true
  network_interface         = aws_network_interface.NginX-public.id
  #associate_with_private_ip = "192.168.100.10"
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.BrokenByte-gateway, aws_instance.BrokenByteNginX]
}

resource "aws_instance" "BrokenByteNginX" {
  ami = "ami-0dba2cb6798deb6d8"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "aws_test"
  network_interface {
       device_index=0
       network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.NginX-LB.id
  }
    network_interface {
       device_index=1
       network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.NginX-public.id
  }
  
  
  tags = {
    Name = "BrokenByteNginXLB"
  }

  user_data =  <<-EOF
               #!/bin/bash
               sudo apt-get update -y
               EOF
}

resource "aws_instance" "BrokenByteWWW1" {
  ami = "ami-0dba2cb6798deb6d8"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "aws_test"
  network_interface {
       device_index=0
       network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.www1.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "BrokenByteWWW1"
  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "BrokenByteWWW2" {
  ami = "ami-0dba2cb6798deb6d8"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "aws_test"
  network_interface {
       device_index=0
       network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.www2.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "BrokenByteWWW2"
  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "BrokenByteWWW3" {
  ami = "ami-0dba2cb6798deb6d8"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "aws_test"
  network_interface {
       device_index=0
       network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.www3.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "BrokenByteWWW3"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of your instances have **public IP address** (except the one with `aws_eip.BrokenByte-PublicIP`), since your public subnet is missing `map_public_ip_on_launch`. You can rectify the issue by:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "BrokenbyteLB-subnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.BrokenByteVPC.id
  cidr_block = "192.168.100.0/28"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "BrokenbyteLB-subnet"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
Yes, I wanted just one instance to have public IP, and will comunicate with other 3,4 via private ip addresses.
I wanted to test Load Balancing, Reverse Proxy in this topology.

I tried, still is not working :(. IP address was assigned on correct instance.

Comment: @zeenmc You have to re-design your network. If you don't want your instances to have public IP, why do you put them in public subnet? They should be in private subnets in this case, not public.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin for your reply. I assigned private subnet, 192.168.100.0/28, or I need to do in some other way ? I need one instance to have public, and it does.

Apparently, I got now Public IP addresses and they are working, just I don't have access to device which has EIP address.

Comment: The subnet `192.168.100.0/28` is public subnet as it has route tables to intnet gateway.

Comment: @zeenmc My guess is that you mixed up interfaces. I'm not sure what you are doing with extra interfaces for this one instnace. Why would you need that if you want to use load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

I was sure is something related to network card, but wasn't sure what.
Now is fine, I can ping and SSH, just swapped public IP to be network 0, and I removed code for network.
@Marcin, your first reply showed me in which direction to look.

```
  # network_interface {
  #      device_index=0
  #      network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.NginX-LB.id
  # }
    network_interface {
       device_index=0
       network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.NginX-public.id
  }
```